# F# Changing parameters precedence

Tags: f#, pipeline, currying

I'm new to F# and have a question about functions pipeline. Let's say we have a function `map` which maps list of functions to array of values creating a list of arrays:

```
//val map : ('a -> 'b) list -> 'a [] -> 'b [] list     
let map funcs vals = 
    funcs |> List.map (fun f -> Array.map f vals)
```

Usage example:

```
//val it : float [] list = [[|1.0; 1.144729886|]; [|15.15426224; 23.14069263|]]
map [log; exp] [|Math.E; Math.PI|]
```

Is there a way to replace lambda function `(fun f -> Array.map f vals)` with a chain of pipeline operators?

I'd like to write smth like:

```
//val map : 'a [] list -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b [] list
let map funcs vals = funcs |> List.map (vals |> Array.map)
```

But this doesn't work.

Many thanks,

Ivan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this one.

```
let map funcs vals = funcs |> List.map (Array.map >> ((|>) vals))
```

The part `Array.map >> ((|>) vals)` partially applies `f` to `Array.map` and then composes it with the application of `vals`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Arguably, this makes code hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the most readable cross-product function would be:

```
let flip f y x = f x y  // a pretty standard function for flipping arguments of function 
let crossProduct funcs vals =
    (<|)
    >> flip Array.map vals
    |> flip List.map funcs

let result = crossProduct [log; exp] [|Math.E; Math.PI|]
```

---

**TL;DR**: A bit of explanation.
The pattern: `xs |> List.map f` is very popular, but sometimes it is better to write:
`f |> List.map <| xs`
Or, using `flip`: `f |> flip List.map xs`
Considering this, let's write the function in the most straightforward way:

```
let cartesianProduct0 funcs vals =
    fun f ->
        fun v -> f v
        |> (flip Array.map vals)
    |> (flip List.map funcs)
```

Then you notice that `fun v -> f v` is actually `(<)`:

```
fun f ->
    ((<|) f)
    |> (flip Array.map vals)
```

or:

```
fun f ->
    f
    |> (<|)
    |> (flip Array.map vals)
```

or, simply:

```
(<|)
>> flip Array.map vals
```

The rest you need to do is just a minor style refactoring.